# YouTube API v3, iOS App authentication for company YouTube account

Tags: ios, api, video, youtube

What I want to do in a nutshell:
In our app I want to be able to upload videos to our company YouTube account. Our app has 'host' users and 'guest' users. The host can upload videos for a guest. The video will be unlisted so they're not available publicly and the guest will get a message in the app telling them that a new video is available. We'll then play the video in the app using the YouTube link.

I've downloaded the google-api-objectivec-client source and integrated it in the project. I've studied the YouTube example application that comes along with it. In this example application the user logs into her own account using OAuth 2.0 which is not our use case. The app should have authorization to upload videos to our company account without bothering the user.

I've read a lot of documentation and searched the web to see if someone else has solved this but I was not able to find the right solution.

My Question:
How should our app get authorization to upload videos? Using API keys, using Google+, using a service account? If someone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment.